# play morphia find a Reference object by ObjectId

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, morphia

I have the following class "Ground":

```
@Entity("grounds")
public class Ground {

@Id
public String id;

public String name;
public String password;

@Reference
List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();
```

I created a new Ground and added one member as `@Reference`. When I try to find the ground by the member `@Id` I just get an empty query. Here's my code:

```
    Datastore ds = Database.getDatastore();
    User member = ds.get(User.class, new ObjectId(id));

    Query<Ground> query = ds.createQuery(Ground.class).disableValidation()
            .filter("members", member);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. While I don't see `User`: Do you define `@Id` as a `String` as well? Because in your query you use an `ObjectId`.
2. I think you need to query references with a key, for example

   ```
   Query<Ground> query = ds.createQuery(Ground.class).disableValidation()
       .field("members").hasThisElement(ds.getKey(member));
   ```

Comment: I defined @Id in User as a String and tried to query my references with a key but I got this error:
MappingException: Could not map models.Ground
Now I changed my List to Embedded. This works for me. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Ok, good that you were able to fix it. I've also cleaned up my code, since there was a better solution — just for the reference